# In R, can I change histogram title without specify `main=`?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

Ok, suppose I create a very simple histogram with my function:

```
hist(my.fun(100))
```

The title of my histogram show `Histogram of my.fun(100)`. This is perfectly fine for me! I like the way R automatically recognize `my.fun(100)` and put it in the title and label.

But then I do complex computation, says:

```
n <- my.complex.algo.that.compute.size(args)
hist(my.fun(n))
```

This time, the title show `Histogram of my.fun(n)`. Which gives no clue on how large is `n`. I know that `n` will be evaluate to some integer, suppose that for this run `n == 42`, I like to see the title of histogram show `Histogram of my.fun(42)` instead.

Is this possible *without* specifying the title by myself (no `main=paste(...)`). I've try these and fail:

```
hist(my.fun(`n`))
hist(my.fun(eval(n)))
```

Comment: "How can I do something in R without using the argument that's provided to do exactly that?" is a very odd question. Obviously your attempts fail. On the help page of `hist` it says you change the title with the argument `main`. If you don't like that, you write your own hist function that does what you want.

Comment: Maybe we'd be less perplexed if you explain why? Particularly, "(no main=paste(...))", why?

Comment: I find that R have very weird evaluation aspect (compare to other general purpose language such as C, Python). For this one I'm curious why `hist()` can catch the expression `my.fun(100)` and make it a string in title later!

Comment: @neizod The evaluation aspects of R are nothing weird once you understand them. R comes from the corner of functional programming languages, and works with closures. If you look at the source code of `hist`, you see immediately how exactly the function does that. Or Spacedman's answer shows you that as well.

Comment: @JorisMeys since I'm very new to R, I don't know where to look for the source code of `hist` function (I've try searching for `hist` on <https://github.com/wch/r-source> and felt overwhelmed). A link to exact file is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @neizod You can just type the name of the function at the console -without parentheses! - press enter, and you see the source code of that function. If you want to know more about the evaluation system `hist` uses, check this page: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html

Comment: You don't know where to look for the source code of `hist`? There's a [question for that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19226816/271616). ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I look up and learn from `hist` source code, I can say that this is impossible when `hist` is called as *top level* function. Because of this line in the source code:

```
xname <- paste(deparse(substitute(x), 500), collapse = "\n")
```

The `deparse(substitute(x))` try to catch (not-yet-evaluated) expression tree and turn it into a string. This mean whatever expression I type as first argument for the `hist` function, it will be turned into a string right away without any evaluation.

To achieve this, I need to force evaluation at some leaf of the expression tree. Which (luckily enough that I just learn about it) can be done with `substitute`, and use `do.call` to pass the evaluated expression tree as an argument for `hist` function:

```
n <- my.complex.algo.that.compute.size(user.args)   # suppose this calc return 42
evaluated.arg <- substitute(my.fun(x), list(x=n))   # now this will be my.fun(42)
do.call(hist, list(evaluated.arg))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you restrict the thing you are histogramming to a function of a single argument, n, then you can do this:

```
nhist = function(f,n){
   hist(f(n),
   main=paste0(
     "Histogram of ",
     deparse(substitute(f), 500),"
     (",n,")", collapse = "\n"))}
```

Which you call slightly differently:

```
Z=100
nhist(runif, Z)
```

You have to pass `f` and `n` separately since there's no way `hist` can figure out what was passed to `f`.